# Java - Arrays/Loops

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I wanted to display the second highest and second lowest number in a given random array values ranges from(0 to 999999) and also the way the highest number will be printed in tagalog word and the shortest number will be printed in Spanish word. Here is by far is my work,can you cite or add some code for it to work? I'm having a hard time on my Main method and connecting all of them.

```
package demo;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MachineProject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 5;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array=new int[5];
    System.out.println("Input 6 numbers between 0 and 999,999 :");
      number = in.nextInt();
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            array[i]=in.nextInt(); 
            }
        if(number>=0 && number<=999999){
            if(number==0){
                System.out.print("NUMBER AFTER CONVERSION:\tZERO");
            } else {
                System.out.print("NUMBER AFTER CONVERSION:\t");
                convertNumberToWordsTagalog(((number / 100) % 10), " HUNDRED");
                convertNumberToWordsSpanish((number % 100), " ");
            }

        } else{
            System.out.print("NUMBER OUT OF RANGE");
        }
        System.out.print("\nPlease type a number between 0 and 999 OR type -1 to exit:  ");
        number = in.nextInt();
    }


public static final String[] unitsSpanish = {
        "", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete",
        "ocho", "nueve", "diez", "once", "doce", "trece", "catorce",
        "quince", "dieciseis", "diecisiete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve"
};
public static final String[] tensSpanish = {
        "",        // 0
        "",        // 1
        "veinte",  // 20
        "treinta",  // 30
        "cuarenta",   // 40
        "cincuenta",   // 50
        "sesenta",   // 60
        "setenta", // 70
        "ochenta",  // 80
        "noventa"   // 90
};

public static final String[] unitsTagalog = {
        "", "isa", "dalawa", "tatlo", "apat", "lima", "anim", "pito",
        "walo", "siyam", "sampu", "labing isa", "labing dalawa", "labing tatlo", "labing apat",
        "labing lima", "labing anim", "labing pito", "labing walo", "labing siyam"
        // 0-19
};

 public static final String[] tensTagalog = {
            "",        // 0
            "",        // 1
            "dalawampu",  // 20
            "tatlumpu",  // 30
            "apat-na-pu",   // 40
            "limampu",   // 50
            "anim-na-pu",   // 60
            "pitumpu", // 70
            "walumpu",  // 80
            "siyam-na-pu"   // 90
    };

 public static String convertNumberToWordsTagalog(final int num) {
        if (num < 20) {
            return unitsTagalog[num];
        }

        if (num < 100) {
            return tensTagalog[num / 10] + ((num % 10 != 0) ? " " : "") + unitsTagalog[num % 10];
        }

        if (num < 1000) {
            return unitsTagalog[num / 100] + " daan" + ((num % 100 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWordsTagalog(num % 100);
        }
            return convertNumberToWordsTagalog(num / 1000) + " libo" + ((num % 1000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWordsTagalog(num % 1000);

        }

    public static String convertNumberToWordsSpanish(final int num) {
        if (num < 20) {
            return unitsSpanish[num];
        }

        if (num < 100) {
            return tensSpanish[num / 10] + ((num % 10 != 0) ? " " : "") + unitsSpanish[num % 10];
        }

        if (num < 1000) {
            return unitsSpanish[num / 100] + " cien" + ((num % 100 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWordsSpanish(num % 100);
        }
            return convertNumberToWordsSpanish(num / 1000) + " mil" + ((num % 1000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWordsSpanish(num % 1000);

        }

static void SecondSmallest(int arr[]) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Input size of an array
    int n = in.nextInt();

    //Array declaration
    int arr1[] = new int[n];

    //Taking an input value of an array
    for (int j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
       arr1[j] = in.nextInt();
    }

    //Initialize with max value of integer
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int secondSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    //Traverse an array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {

      if (smallest > arr1[i]) {
         secondSmallest = smallest;
         smallest = arr1[i];

     }

     if (arr1[i] > smallest && arr1[i] < secondSmallest) {
        secondSmallest = arr1[i];
     }
   }
   in.close();
   System.out.println("Second smallest number is " + secondSmallest);
 }




public static void SecondHighest(int arr[], int second_max) {
     int max = 0, temp, numbers;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        numbers = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                max = in.nextInt();
            } else {
                temp = in.nextInt();
                if (temp > max) {
                    second_max = max;
                    max = temp;
                }
                else if(temp>second_max)
                {
                 second_max=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Second highest number :" + second_max);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you break this down into easy-to-chew portions.  Start with writing (and debugging) the code necessary to entire user input into an array **then** figure out how to find the highest (or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you store the numbers into an `array`, but you never use it.
The same for

```
System.out.print("\nPlease type a number between 0 and 999 OR type -1 to exit:  ");
        number = in.nextInt();
```

If you want to just find the *min* and *max*, you don't need to store every value.
You can look for *min* and *max* while the user inputs the numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_VALUE = 999999;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int second_min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int second_max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to insert? (0 or a negative number to exit)");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    if (n <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Input "+n+" integers between 0 and " + MAX_VALUE + " :");

    int val; // this integer will be used to check the input
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        do {
            val = in.nextInt();
            if ((val < 0) || (val > MAX_VALUE)) {
                System.out.println("Error: NUMBER OUT OF RANGE");
                System.out.println("Please insert a valid number");
            }
        } while ((val < 0) || (val > MAX_VALUE));
        // Now we're sure that val contains a valid number

        if (val < min) {
            second_min = min;
            min = val;
        } else if (val < second_min) {
            second_min = val;
        }
        if (val > max) {
            second_max = max;
            max = val;
        } else if (val > second_max) {
            second_max = val;
        }
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.print("Min (in Spanish):\t");
    if (min == 0) {
        System.out.println("Zero");
    } else {
        System.out.println(convertNumberToWordsSpanish(min));
    }
    System.out.println("Second smallest number: " + second_min);
    System.out.println("Second highest number: " + second_max);
    System.out.print("Max (in Tagalog):\t");
    if (max == 0) { // Keep in mind that the user could input N zeros
        System.out.println("Zero");
    } else {
        System.out.println(convertNumberToWordsTagalog(max));
    }
}
```

If you need to store the numbers into an array, you could remove the code for searching *min* and *max*, and use [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) so

```
final int min = array[0];
final int second_min = array[1];
final int second_max = array[n-2];
final int max = array[n-1];
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer but it seems the Spanish and tagalog translation is wrong.